# Pesky "Table 'my_table' already exists" in Django-South

Tags: django, django-south

In Django-South: 
I changed I've run the initial migration successfully for myapp but for some reason, after I've made a change to my model and go to

```
./manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
./manage.py migrate myapp
```

And I get a lot of traceback which ends in:

```
(1050, "Table 'my_table' already exists")
```

After much googling, I found and tried this:

```
./manage.py migrate myapp --fake
```

And then I proceed to migrate it, to no avail; same error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried dropping the table?

Comment: Yes. Dropped the table, and it seemed to work, but then when I make another change to the model, I get the same error. So do I have to drop the table each time? If so, what is the point of South? I could do that myself.

Comment: did you run manage.py syncdb after installing south? South needs its own table in order to save the migrations, make sure you have a south migrations table in your database. South is great once you have it set up correctly, definitely worth the learning curve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just got this same error, and found this question by search.

My problem was that my second migration I'd created using the `--initial` flag, i.e.

```
$ ./manage.py startapp foo
$ ./manage.py schemamigration --initial foo
$ ./manage.py migrate foo
```

... make some changes to foo ...

```
$ ./manage.py schemamigration --initial foo
```

(oops!)

```
$ ./manage.py migrate foo
```

... and I get the error, and the migration fails because in the second migration, South is trying to create a table its already created.

### Solution

In my migrations folder:

```
$ ls foo/migrations
0001_initial.py   0002_initial.py
```

remove that second migration and re-export the second migration with the correct `--auto` flag:

```
$ rm foo/migrations/0002_initial.py
$ ./manage.py schemamigration --auto foo
$ ./manage.py migrate foo
```

Success!

There may be other things that cause this error, but that was my bad!

Comment: To anyone doing this, remember to backup your schemas just in case. Also if you ran `schemamigration --initial` multiple times then remove all of the schemas except `0001` and `0002`.

Answer (score 4):

Is it an existing app?

In that case you will need to convert it in addition to the fake bit.

There are good docs [here](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app) on converting an existing app.

Although they are quite tricky to find if you don't know where they are already ( ;

For converting, after adding south to your installed apps:

```
./manage.py syncdb
./manage.py convert_to_south myapp
./manage.py migrate myapp 0001 --fake
```

Comment: It's not an existing app, so that I why I'm a little confused. This had South from the start.

Answer (score 0):

this problem actually happens if one of the cases:

1) You made "schemamigration app_name --initial" after one is "--auto"
2) You interrupted the last migration you have made.

To resolve such problem you apply the following:

1) mark your last schema migration as fake.

```
python manage.py schemamigration app_name --fake
```

Note: Make sure that the schema of models is same as schema of tables in database.

2) apply the migration again by doing

```
python manage.py schemamigration app_Name --auto
python manage.py migrate app-Name
```

Note: sometimes you might add **manually** a specific field you already added using the following syntax.

```
python manage.py schemamigration app_name --add-field My_model.added_field
```

For more info. regarding south, you could check its documentation [here](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html).